# Template Haskell compile error when calling with different parameters

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Why does the following fail to compile (on GHC 7.4.2)?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

f1 = $([| id |])

main = print $ (f1 (42 :: Int), f1 (42 :: Integer))
```

Note that the following compiles fine:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

f1 = id -- Don't use template Haskell here.

main = print $ (f1 (42 :: Int), f1 (42 :: Integer))
```

Is there a language extension I can use to make the former compile?

*I know the Template Haskell seems silly in this example, but it's a simplified version of a more complex problem, which requires Template Haskell to process arbitrary sized tuples.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `f1` is assigned the type `Integer -> Integer` instead of the more general `a -> a` for some reason. Adding an explicit type signature makes your example compile fine for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

f1 :: a -> a
f1 = $([| id |])

main = print $ (f1 (42 :: Int), f1 (42 :: Integer))
```